# Spin combinations forming representation of $\text{SU}(2)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

I'm currently reading Griffiths' book about particle physics. On page 183, after showing a basis for a system of three spin-1/2 particles (tripe product space of up and down states), he says

> In the language of group theory, the direct product of three fundamental (two-dimensional) representations of $\text{SU}(2)$ decomposes into the direct sum of a four-dimensional representation and two two-dimensional representations

I understand the decomposition in terms of dimensions or the degenerate eigenspaces of the square of the spin operator. I know basic group theory and looked up the definition of a representation, but I dont understand how this relates to representations of $\text{SU}(2)$.

I tried to google my way to an understanding but could not find out enough and still have questions

What do m-dimensional representations of $\text{SU}(2)$ have to do with spin systems? Can someone show me the decomposition in terms of group theory and then link it to quantum mechanics (and how spinors spaces relate to this)? A rotation by 360 degrees in physical space is just a rotation by 180 degrees in spin space, this is encoded in the fact that the representations of $\text{SU}(2)$ are a double covering of Euclidean three space. Why is that? I think I did not understand the definition of a double covering properly. Can you map rotations in Euclidean space to rotations in spin space and see the representations of SU(2) coming up?

Comment: $SU(2)$ is the double cover of $SO(3)$, not Euclidean space. The spin states of a spin$-s$ particle are elements of a $2S+1$-dimensional representation of $SU(2)$. You might find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients) useful to read too?

Comment: Yes, I meant to say the Rotations in euclidean space, sorry. The decomposition in terms of State Vectors using Clebsch-Gordan-Coefficients I understand, but not really how this relates to SU(2). I don't understand why the Representation of Spin Operators in Spinor Space are a Representation of SU(2) and why you say stat the States are Elements of it. Aren't the States what the Representation Acts on? For example [link](https://hepwww.pp.rl.ac.uk/users/haywood/Group_Theory_Lectures/Lecture_3.pdf) here on the first pages they show the Representations of SU(2) in 2 and 3 dimensions.

Comment: And I'm also in interested in how the fact that SU(2) is a double cover of SO(3) encodes the fact that 2phi-Rotations around an Axis in real space are only phi-Rotations in Spin Space (how would you map the rotations for example?).